# Is there any way to make simplejson less strict?

Tags: python, json, simplejson

I'm interested in having `simplejson.loads()` successfully parse the following:

```
{foo:3}
```

It throws a `JSONDecodeError` saying "expecting property name" but in reality it's saying "I require double quotes around my property names".  This is annoying for my use case, and I'd prefer a less strict behavior.  I've read the docs, but beyond making my own decoder class, I don't see anything obvious that changes this behavior.

Comment: So you want `simplejson` accept something that's not valid JSON? (It's JavaScript where the quotes are optional. In JSON they're mandatory.)

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I want. :)

Comment: What I was implying is "this is something you shouldn't want in the first place."

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not JSON, but what I'm parsing is written by a person, so I want to be lenient.  The YAML solution (below) is great.

Comment: YAML is probably the better option if you want human authoring, yes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use YAML (>=1.2)as it is a superset of JSON, you can do:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> s = '{foo: 8}'
>>> yaml.load(s)
{'foo': 8}
```

Comment: @slacy I just noticed that yaml needs a space after colon.I think this will spoil your party.

Comment: It does, unless the RHS is an array.  {foo:[bar]} is fine, which is actually what I'm doing.

Comment: As RanRag said, yaml will fail if there is no space after colon, for example: `yaml.load('{a:"b"}')`

Comment: @suud: i still don't understand the downvote because I have clearly  mentioned that yaml will fail in that particular scenario and OP was fine with it. So, why the downvote?

Comment: Sometimes a question in SO despite looks like a specific question, it can be represented as general question, that's why you can see some questions here are marked as duplicated question. I have same question with the OP and I downvoted your answer because your solution is not perfect. Is it clear enough? :)

Comment: @suud : I got your point. Can you please share the perfect solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [demjson](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/).

```
>>> import demjson
>>> demjson.decode('{foo:3}')
{u'foo': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.  To successfully parse that using simplejson you would first need to transform it into a valid JSON string.

Depending on how strict the format of your incoming string is this could be pretty simple or extremely complex.

For a simple case, if you will always have a JSON object that only has letters and underscores in keys (without quotes) and integers as values, you could use the following to transform it into valid JSON:

```
import re
your_string = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z_]+)', r'"\1"', your_string)
```

For example:

```
>>> re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z_]+)', r'"\1"', '{foo:3, bar:4}')
'{"foo":3, "bar":4}'
```