# How To Deal With Un-Format Json Data In Python?

Tags: python

I am new to regular expression, I want to get the content between 'query:' and ',"' .
the example data likes here https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/suggest?q=hello .
I tried the regular string like "^query(.*),"$", but it not worked, I don't know why, and how can I deal with the problem?

Comment: This is JSON data, don't parse it with regular expressions. Use Python's [built-in JSON parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: But it is not the stand format of json data, I have to re-format it before I can use.

Comment: Indeed you're right; it's not standard JSON. But it looks like you can parse it using YAML, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104930/is-there-any-way-to-make-simplejson-less-strict) (once you've installed the PyYAML library). You'll also need to add spaces after each colon, so your line will look something like `import yaml; import urllib2; data = yaml.load(urllib2.urlopen("https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/suggest?q=hello").read().replace(":", ": "))`. Does that work for you?

Comment: yaml is the best way to solve my problem, thanks for you advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you REALLY want to extract text by using regex, try this one:

```
import re

a_pattern = re.compile("query\:(.+?)\,")
re.findall(a_pattern, 'query:text_you_want_to_extract,')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try re.split() with " as the delimiter:

re.split('[\"]+','query:"some text here"')

Your output will be something like:
['query:', 'some text here', '']